# Page loading takes long and how to deal the cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have many pages in my web app where its taking time to load the pages. In the below example, I would like to avoid or reduce the using of `cy.wait()` as it is not ideal. How can we apply `cy.route()` in this example, can we create a common function and use that we ever possible ? 
 *note: Dev team are converting some old pages to `React` and dealing loading issues.*

//test.spec.js

```
 cy.wait(5000);
 cy.bookspanel.getBookNavigationTab();
```

//bookhelpfunctions.js

```
cy.bookspanel = {
    getBookNavigationTab: function () {
        return cy.get('a > span').contains("Books").click();
    }
}
```

//index.js

```
import './bookhelpfunctions'
```

```html
<a class="sc-iybRtq eCauUN" href="/spa/books?candidateStatusId=44501c83-5652-4462-9512-2e482514e28f"><span class="sc-iQtOjA hRzpyH"></span><span class="sc-cEvuZC gFbQRN">Books</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `cy.get()` for something that only appears after the page load is finished,

```
cy.bookspanel = {
  getBookNavigationTab: function () {
    cy.get('a > span').contains("Books").click();
    cy.contains('h2', 'Heading that displays after page is loaded');  
    // Will not run next command until above heading appears.
  }
}
```

or pass to the function as a parameter if it changes on each page

```
cy.bookspanel = {
  getBookNavigationTab: function (myContent) {
    cy.get('a > span').contains("Books").click();
    cy.contains(myContent);  
    // Will not run next command until above content appears.
  }
}

cy.bookspanel.getBookNavigationTab('Heading that displays after page is loaded');
```

Comment: Could you please explain the flow  in the second example `pass to the function as a parameter`

Comment: I am not sure what you don't understand. Commands are executed in the order they are run, so `cy.contains(myContent)` will either wait up to the default timeout, or fail if content does not appear. Any commands after `cy.bookspanel.getBookNavigationTab('Heading that displays after page is loaded');` will wait for that one to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem fully, but if you have some kind of [loader](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp) (some animation for loading) on your site while the page is loading, you could do such trick:

```
cy.get('.loaderClassName'), { timeout: 3000 }).should("not.exist")
```

or, even better, with [data-cy](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements) (then you could even choose loaders for particular sections/elements:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=loader]'), { timeout: 3000 }).should("not.exist")
```

This way, you are not hardcoding any values in cy.wait (you are right, you shouldn't do this). In the above solution, the moment the loader disappears (so from the user's point of view, the page is visible and ready), you may start testing.

Additionally, you may set whatever the timeout you want (in milliseconds), to suit it to your requirements (to make sure the loading doesn't exceed a given amount of time).

Then, you may use this line in the beginning of the function to make sure everything is loaded in specific time, so in your example:

```
cy.bookspanel = {
    getBookNavigationTab: function () {
        cy.get('[data-cy=loader]'), { timeout: 3000 }).should("not.exist")
        return cy.get('a > span').contains("Books").click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not the one I am looking for. I simply want to avoid `cy.wait()`. May be  `cy.route()` can help ?, I am not sure...or any other custom method instead of wait ...

Comment: @soccerway well then, what about just adding timeout value? 
`cy.get('a > span', {timeout:10000}).contains("Books").click();`
This will try to get the element, it will query for it max. 10 seconds. So instead of always waiting 3 seconds (when you are using cy.wait()), if the element if found earlier (e.g. adter 1 second), it will be returned earlier.